# Luasocket на ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

Всем привет!Собираю Verlihub 1.0.0 на ubuntu 12, все работает, кроме луасокетов.Может ли кто нибудь помочь их собрать. Ранее ставил хабы на других nix-ОС, и всегда устанавливается все, кроме луасокетов.Я уж не знаю что делать.

```
ubuntu:~/soc/luasocket-2.0.2$ makecd src; make allmake[1]: Вход в каталог `/home/user/soc/luasocket-2.0.2/src'gcc  -DLUASOCKET_DEBUG  -pedantic -Wall -O2 -fpic   -c -o luasocket.o luasocket.cluasocket.c:20:17: фатальная ошибка: lua.h: Нет такого файла или каталогакомпиляция прервана.make[1]: *** [luasocket.o] Ошибка 1make[1]: Выход из каталога `/home/user/soc/luasocket-2.0.2/src'make: *** [all] Ошибка 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Ну, как девять лет назад советовал Дэниел Сильверстоун, надо бы ещё доустановить liblua50-dev и liblualib50-dev. Вот: [debian: no lua.h](http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2003-09/msg00103.html)

Comment: и их я тоже у становил.прочитал все возможные маны, которыей в интернете написаны.например этот (из последних) http://admiral.dchab.com/?q=node/84